# Use map on each elements of multi dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

For example I have 300x600 numpy array. I want to use map's lambda to modify in-place of every value in this array with some if conditions. (e.g. if a cell is <100 then it will became 0, otherwise do nothing)

Using `map` and `lambda` turns out that each variable in lambda is an array of size 600. Do you have any elegant function where I am able to iterate through all elements of array of any size and modify them in place?

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
In [2]: arr = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)

In [3]: arr
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [4]: arr[arr % 3 == 0] = 42

In [5]: arr
Out[5]: 
array([[42,  1,  2, 42,  4],
       [ 5, 42,  7,  8, 42],
       [10, 11, 42, 13, 14],
       [42, 16, 17, 42, 19],
       [20, 42, 22, 23, 42]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
f=np.vectorize(<lambda>)
f(a)
```